# Postgres to Postgres replication error in AWS DMS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, data-migration, dms

I am getting below error while using AWS data migration service.

**Source** - One single postgres rds instance having multiple databases in it (80 GB)

**Target** - One single postgres rds instance where each src database will be a schema in same database

**Number of tables** - Total number of tables including all databases is around 200

**Replication instance** - t2.medium

I created four tasks for replicating four databases from source into four different schemas in target. But the fifth task for fifth database is failing with below error -

> ERROR: all replication slots are in use;, Error while executing the
>   query

How can I increase the replication slots so that dms can have 10 tasks running together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, There is an option to configure maximum number of replication slots in aws postgres rds instance which should solve my issue.
[image]